# Compartir leyenda para multigráfico con ggplot

Tags: r

Tengo un código con el que elaboro dos gráficos a partir de mis datos (variable dependiente "en", variables independientes "time", "coor", "cont":

```
en <- c(3,3,2.8,2.9,2.5,2,2.1,2,1.25,1,0.4,0.6)
time <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
coor <- c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1)
cont <- c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1)

library(ggplot2)

f <-subset(global_data,coor==0)
plot1<-ggplot(f, aes(time)) + 
  geom_boxplot(coef =1.5, aes(x=time, y=en, fill=cont), outlier.size = NULL) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 3)) +
  guides(fill=FALSE) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14),
        axis.title=element_text(size=14,face="bold"))
d <-subset(global_data,coor==0.5)
plot2<-ggplot(d, aes(time)) + 
  geom_boxplot(coef =1.5, aes(x=time, y=en, fill=cont), outlier.size = NULL) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 3)) +
  guides(fill=FALSE) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14),
        axis.title=element_text(size=14,face="bold"))
```

Ahora junto los gráficos:

```
grid.arrange(plot1,plot2,ncol=2)
```

La leyenda original, que oculto en los gráficos mediante `guides(fill=FALSE)` está generada por los 10 niveles de la variable denominada "cont". Me gustaría que esa leyenda apareciera en la parte de abajo de mi multigráfico.

He intentado [varias soluciones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649473/add-a-common-legend-for-combined-ggplots) sin éxito.

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir al menos un ejemplo mínimo de los datos, como para reproducir la gráfica? Saludos.

Comment: si no me equivoco mucho, porque los datos originales corresponden a un fichero inmeso, el ejemplo que he añadido serviría de ejemplo mínimo. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que podrías hacer es usar `theme(legend.position="bottom")`, ajuste un poco tus datos, a `cont`le di los 10 niveles que mencionas y genere algunos casos más. El ejemplo quedaría así:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

set.seed(1100)
en <- c(3,3,2.8,2.9,2.5,2,2.1,2,1.25,1,0.4,0.6)
time <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
coor <- c(0,0.5,0,0.5,0,0.5,0,0.5,0,0.5,0,0.5)
cont <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

global_data <- data.frame(en=sample(en,100,replace=TRUE),
                          time=factor(sample(time,100,replace=TRUE)),
                          coor=sample(coor,100,replace=TRUE),
                          cont=factor(sample(cont,100,replace=TRUE)))

f <-subset(global_data,coor==0)
plot1<-ggplot(f, aes(time)) + 
    geom_boxplot(coef =1.5, aes(x=time, y=en, fill=cont), outlier.size = NULL) + 
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 3)) +
    theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14),
          axis.title=element_text(size=14,face="bold")) +
    theme(legend.position="bottom")

d <-subset(global_data,coor==0.5)
plot2<-ggplot(d, aes(time)) + 
    geom_boxplot(coef =1.5, aes(x=time, y=en, fill=cont), outlier.size = NULL) + 
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 3)) +
    theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14),
          axis.title=element_text(size=14,face="bold")) +
    theme(legend.position="bottom")

grid.arrange(plot1,plot2,ncol=2)
```

El resultado final:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puede molestar un poco tener las dos leyendas en ambos gráfico, en particular por que es básicamente el mismo indicador, podemos dejar una sola leyenda usando `guides(fill=FALSE)` en uno de los gráficos, pero ahí lo que ocurriría es que un gráfico sería más pequeño que el otro por que obviamente debe dejar espacio para ubicar la leyenda. Otra posibilidad interesante ([fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26193868/6836377)) podría ser usar [`facet_wrap()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/1.0.0/topics/facet_wrap), que te permite organizar varios gráficos en función de una formula, en este caso usaremos `coor` y estableciendo cuantas columnas vamos a querer, automáticamente los gráficos se irán ajustando y como verás la leyenda se dibuja una sola vez.

```
gg <- ggplot(global_data, aes(x=interaction(time, cont), y=en))
gg <- gg + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=cont))
gg <- gg + facet_wrap(~coor, ncol=2)
gg <- gg + labs(x="")
gg <- gg + theme_bw()
gg <- gg + theme(strip.background=element_rect(fill="black"))
gg <- gg + theme(strip.text=element_text(color="white", face="bold"))
gg <- gg + theme(legend.position="bottom")
gg <- gg + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, size=8))
gg
```

El resultado final:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias. La primera solución que propones la había intentado, pero en efecto, un gráfico queda más grande que el otro. La segunda solución es muy buena. Sin embargo, el problema es que mis datos reales tienen 10 niveles para la variable "coor", así que me queda todo como muy comprimido. Volviendo a tu primera solución, estaba pensando en si podría "extraer" la leyenda de una de las gráficas y añadirla al grid.arrange. A ver si doy con la clave ;)

Comment: Muchas gracias... una consulta. Cuando trato de guardar el grafico como objeto para exportarlo, me sale NULL

Answer (score 1):

En adición a la buena respuesta ya dada, dejo a continuación una alternativa que he encontrado y que da bastante flexibilidad a la hora de compartir la leyenda y generar el gráfico.

Primero el código que ya conocemos para generar los datos y los gráficos:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

set.seed(1100)
en <- c(3,3,2.8,2.9,2.5,2,2.1,2,1.25,1,0.4,0.6)
time <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
coor <- c(0,0.5,0,0.5,0,0.5,0,0.5,0,0.5,0,0.5)
cont <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

global_data <- data.frame(en=sample(en,100,replace=TRUE),
                          time=factor(sample(time,100,replace=TRUE)),
                          coor=sample(coor,100,replace=TRUE),
                          cont=factor(sample(cont,100,replace=TRUE)))

f <-subset(global_data,coor==0)
plot1<-ggplot(f, aes(time)) + 
    geom_boxplot(coef =1.5, aes(x=time, y=en, fill=cont), outlier.size = NULL) + 
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 3)) +
    theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14),
          axis.title=element_text(size=14,face="bold")) +
    theme(legend.position="bottom")

d <-subset(global_data,coor==0.5)
plot2<-ggplot(d, aes(time)) + 
    geom_boxplot(coef =1.5, aes(x=time, y=en, fill=cont), outlier.size = NULL) + 
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 3)) +
    theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14),
          axis.title=element_text(size=14,face="bold")) +
    theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

A continuación la función para extraer las leyendas y combinarlas en una sola al pie del multigráfico:

```
grid_arrange_shared_legend <- function(..., nrow = 1, ncol = length(list(...)), position = c("bottom", "right")) {

  plots <- list(...)
  position <- match.arg(position)
  g <- ggplotGrob(plots[[1]] + theme(legend.position = position))$grobs
  legend <- g[[which(sapply(g, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")]]
  lheight <- sum(legend$height)
  lwidth <- sum(legend$width)
  gl <- lapply(plots, function(x) x + theme(legend.position = "none"))
  gl <- c(gl, nrow = nrow, ncol = ncol)

  combined <- switch(position,
                     "bottom" = arrangeGrob(do.call(arrangeGrob, gl),
                                            legend,
                                            ncol = 1,
                                            heights = unit.c(unit(1, "npc") - lheight, lheight)),
                     "right" = arrangeGrob(do.call(arrangeGrob, gl),
                                           legend,
                                           ncol = 2,
                                           widths = unit.c(unit(1, "npc") - lwidth, lwidth)))
  grid.newpage()
  grid.draw(combined)

}
```

Finalmente utilizamos la función para realizar el multigráfico. Nótese la flexibilidad que permite el manejo de número de columnas y filas.

```
grid_arrange_shared_legend(plot1, plot2, nrow = 1, ncol = 2)
```

A continuación el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]